# use of RequiredFieldValidator arrests form

Tags: c#

I have used a RequiredFieldValidator in a text box items now they work fine but when they triggered and then the user wants to discard the form like want to exit from that form so these (RequiredFieldValidator) don't allow it . it's like locked. how to avoid this. I am using C# in ASP.NET and a beginner

Regards

Comment: What action user performs to exit the form?

Comment: clcking on any link in that page so as to move to another page  or clicking on links in master page? for button i found this CausesValidation="False" but for links??